# Prove that an array will have at least one local minimum given some constraints

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let's define an array $A[1 \dots n]$, where $A[1] \geq A[2]$ and $A[n-1] \leq A[n]$.

An element is considered a local minimum if $A[i-1] \geq A[i]$ and $A[i+1] \geq A[i]$ (i.e $A[i]$ is less or equal to both of it's neighbours).

For example: $[9,\underline{7},7,\underline{2},8]$

**With this constraints we want to prove that $A$ will have at least one local minimum.**

So here is my attempt (I don't know if it's right, probably is wrong):

Let's prove by induction.

**Base case $n = 3$**: It's trivial to see given the constraints that if $A[1] \geq A[2]$ and $A[2] \leq A[3]$, $A[2]$ is a local minimum.

**H.I**: Let's assume that is valid for $m \leq n$ and proof for $n+1$

Assume that we have something like this $[\dots x ,y \dots]$ and we are going to insert a value $z$ between this two numbers ($[\dots x,z,y \dots]$).

If $z \leq x$ and $z \leq y$ then $z$ is a local minimum (so we guarantee that we have at least one local minimum)

If $z \geq x$ and $z < y$ then the subarray to the left of $z$ (including it $[\dots x,z]$) will satisfy the constraint and have $m \leq n$ elements. By **H.I** this will be valid.

If $z \geq y$ and $z < x$ then the subarray to the right of $z$ (including it $[z,y \dots]$) will satisfy the constraint and have $m \leq n$ elements. By **H.I** this will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let us associate a **Polarity** $+1$ or $-1$ based on this Criteria:

$P(x) = +1$ if $A[x]<A[x+1]$
$P(x) = -1$ if $A[x]>A[x+1]$

It is a local Minimum at $x$ when $P(x) = -1$ & $P(x+1) = +1$

We are given $P(1) = -1$ & $P(n-1) = +1$

The Polarity start at $-1$ and can remain at $-1$, but there must be **some Index where Polarity changes** to $+1$ because the array terminates with Polarity $+1$.
That Index is a local minimum.

This is the Case where the numbers are **Distinct**.

When the numbers are not necessarily Distinct, Polarity $P(x) = 0$ if $A[x]=A[x+1]$

The Polarity starts at $-1$ and can remain at $-1$, but there must be some Index where Polarity changes to $0$ or $+1$ because the array terminates with Polarity $+1$.
That Index is a local minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one  $j \in [2,n-1]$ such that $A(j)$ is minimal among
$A[2],\ldots,A[n-1]$. This will also be a local minimum  due to the given constraints. There may be additional local minima as well.